# print unique permutations of pairs from an array

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

Given an array, print out all non duplicate and non same permutation of pairs from an array. Array does not contain duplicate elements.
Eg:

```
String[] array = {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives", "Chicken"}
```

Desired Example Output:

1. Cheese, Pepperoni
2. Cheese, Black Olives
3. Cheese, Chicken
4. Black Olives, Pepperoni
   ...

Invalid:

1. Cheese, Cheese
2. Cheese, Pepperoni
   Pepperoni, Cheese

Only one input of pairs. [cheese, pepperoni] or [pepperoni, cheese]

```
private Map<Integer, List<String>> getPairs(String[] array) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(array[i]);
                list.add(array[j]);
                map.put(count, list);
                ++count;
            }
        }
        // System.out.println(map);
        return map;
    }
```

My code prints out duplicates. Can you please help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels added implementation. but I am not getting it to work. and it is not a homework.

Comment: NB: `count == map.size()` before and after the inner loop, so `count` is redundant. Also, a map keyed by an "element index" might be simpler as a `List`: you can still access the `i`-th element.

Comment: Is that output the *desired* output or the *actual* output? Whichever it is, please provide the other one too. There are no duplicates in the given output.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes it is an desired output. I have just given an example. It should contain all unique permutations and only one pair of two words. Take a look at the invalid input number 2.

Comment: Close vote retracted, but it is home work whether or not it is homework. This certainly isn't job-related, it's an assignment pure and simple and does not matter (for purposes of this site) if it is self-given or instructor given.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels stack overflow is an website where people come to discuss ideas and problems. job related or assignment or self given or instructor given how does it matter? I stumbled upon a problem so I asked for help. Isnt why stack overflow is meant for. Helping people ?

Comment: Yes it is shawn. We are looking into it.

Comment: @shawnderik SO isn't for discussion - it is a Q&A site. The point about not wanting to help with homework is that an experienced dev can probably give you a simple solution very quickly, but this skips the learning outcome that your instructor wanted you to find by yourself.

Comment: @shawnderik: homework or home work issue does matter, and has been discussed quite extensively in meta. The rules on this are clear, in that an attempt should be shown, and problems with that attempt discussed by the original poster. Otherwise we'd get even more swamped with requests to do other folks homework, and we already get more than enough requests for this already. Again, we're OK on helping with homework, as long as there is adequate demonstration of effort in the question, and surely that's not asking too much. Your initial question did not show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your inner for loop declaration from:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
```

to

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
```

Provided the elements of `array` contain no duplicates, this avoids both the "cheese, cheese" case (since `j` and `i` are never equal), and the "Cheese, Pepperoni" and "Pepperoni, Cheese" case since `j` is never less than `i`.

(The `if (i == j) continue;` is then redundant too)

Comment: Thank you. it worked. I am sorry I could not upvote your answer, I lack the reputation. Thank you again andy. you are awesome.

Comment: Yes, the array does not contain duplicate elements. thanks for the updated answer.

Comment: Here's an upvote. Thanks for helping shawn.